# How to divide ExecutorService tasks into groups or how to invoke shutDownNow only for tasks which have been submitted from the specific main thread?

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, concurrency

In `Spring Boot Application` configuration I declare `@ Bean` :

```
ExecutorService service = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
```

This service is general for the application.

To execute tasks parallel I use:

```
service.submit(() -> {
            if (!Thread.interrupted()) {
                try {
                    ...
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    service.shutdownNow();
                }
            }
        });
```

In case when I have an exception I stop all the tasks. But I need to stop only tasks which have been invoked from the **current thread (current user request)**.

Is It possible to realize It with ExecutorService?

Comment: why don't you use `CompletableFuture` for that?

Comment: I have never heard about It before. I have an opportunity to use anything to solve the problem